# Filename is appended more than once

Tags: for-loop, cmd, append, dos, filenames

I am using a batch file to append multiple file names.

For files: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt, 5.txt - I am wanting to append with copy_1.txt

```
set "nname=copy_"

for %%A in (*.txt) do (
ren %%A %nname%%%A
)
exit
```

However, the loop appears to loop back around to the first file and re-appends the filename.

Here is the cmd output:

```
> for %A in (*.txt) do (ren %A copy_%A )
> (ren 1.txt copy_1.txt )
> (ren 2.txt copy_2.txt )
> (ren 3.txt copy_3.txt )
> (ren 4.txt copy_4.txt )
> (ren 5.txt copy_5.txt )
> (ren copy_1.txt copy_copy_1.txt )
```

Can someone explain to me why this is occuring and how can can avaoid this issue?

I have tried to add an "exception handler" but it has no use.

```
set "nname=copy_"

for %%A in (*.txt) do (
if exist %nname%%%A goto :exit
ren %%A %nname%%%A
)
:exit
echo file exists
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell does not complete its list of files before it begins processing your rename command, so the results of the first rename command, namely copy_1.txt, becomes a match to *.txt.

One way to avoid it:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%A in (`dir /b *.txt`) do (ren %%A %nname%%A)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great, much better than the temporary folder work around I did. Just to be clear, by using the "usebackq" function with the ` is enforcing the shell to complete the looping of *.txt before proceding?

Comment: The /F option allows you to use the output of a command as the "input" to the "for" command.  The "usebackq" option simply changes whether it is a '' string or a `` string that is treated as a command to execute.  (It is better to add the "usebackq" option and put your command within ``.)  What happens then is that the shell processes the text within the `` as a command, executes that command, and then takes the output from that command (stdout from the command) and processes it line-by-line.  Each line is split at space characters into tokens, and the tokens are assigned to the for variables.

Comment: In your loop, you have only one variable, %%A, and so only the first token on each line of output is assigned to %%A.  But the `dir /b *.txt` outputs exactly what you want: one line per file with the file name only.  The fact that the `dir ...` is completed before the "for" loop starts executing is just a vagary of the shell - something I wasn't even sure of until I tested it.